# Problem with reaver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

So I was following up with this link https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/07/learn-to-hack-wifi-password-with-ubuntu.html
I'm stuck with the 7th step. I'm pasting the output of the 6th step just in case if the error is somewhere over there.

```
root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src# ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... no
error: pcap library not found!
root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src# make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src#"
```

[image]

Comment: the `configure` step evaluates your machine for required elements displaying the results (for your mcahine; `pcap` was not found! telling you what needed to be fixed).  You ignored the error & tried the next step expecting results when you should have realized it'd fail due to first step failing...   Your instructions were from 2013-July so were geared for 12.04 LTS or 13.04 most likely.  A quick search of packages (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pcap) indicate libpcap-dev or libpcap0.8 may be required, but I don't know what you're doing (not opening your link sorry)

Comment: Hello again @guiverc, how can I go a step-backward without causing more errors?

Comment: I assumed the mistake was in a previous step, but it was too late. Obviously I was too excited that my earlier error got solved. I understand how unsafe it is opening links.

Comment: fyi: the link may be perfectly safe, it was more I didn't want to, plus I was alluding you to the date (2013-july) which I take into account... tech is an industry that keeps moving; so if I was you, I may have still used the link (if I couldn't find anything later), but would have taken its age into account...  the make & make.install steps did nothing as can't run until prior steps complete (successfully).  because you're compiling the program, the -dev (developer) package may be needed.  No 'step backs' are required.

Comment: well, thanks. I'll put that in concern in the future. I think all of this is in my advantage as for I'm thinking of taking Management & Information Systems as my business major next year. Once again thank you @guiverc

Comment: Complete newbies should **not** dive straight in to compiling source code mere hours after installing the OS.  First learn more about the system and the command line.

Comment: Any helpful links?

Comment: I'm past that by now, I'm stuck here tho 
"root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src# airmon-ng start wlan0

Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill'

  PID Name
  837 avahi-daemon
  850 NetworkManager
  858 wpa_supplicant
  885 avahi-daemon
 4654 dhclient

PHY Interface Driver  Chipset

phy0 wlp7s0  ath9k  Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)"
Should I post another question?

Comment: That's just a warning. Continue with the steps.

Comment: The next step "airodump-ng mon0"  replies with ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063229/how-to-fix-ioctlsiocgifindex-failed-no-such-device?answertab=oldest#tab-top Posted another question, hope you guys help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first ensure that you have enabled all repositories in your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
```

You do not need to compile reaver by yourself since it [is packaged with version 1.4-2build1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=reaver&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all). Use:

```
sudo apt-get install reaver
```

---

If you still need to compile it (with custom `./configure` options or just for new experience) - you should enable *Source code* repositories in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) and install its build-dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep reaver
```

and then continue with `./configure`.

Comment: root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src# sudo apt-get build-dep reaver
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for reaver
root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src#

Comment: Again. Why you want to compile it?

Comment: well, I have interest in network security & hope I can learn in the future, however for the mean time I want to practice on something like hacking my home's wifi & to come up with harder wifi passwords, so I followed up with the link I mentioned in the post.

Comment: @AmrElsokary did you enable the Source Code repository, like N0rbert told you?

Comment: I'm asking because of the fact that Reaver is already packaged in Ubuntu. So compilation is not needed if you plan to use its default built-in functionality. I edited my answer to be clear.

Comment: I enabled everything earlier in software & update, it's still updating tho. Probably some packages wasn't installed when the internet disconnected. It's updating now

Comment: well, I'm new to ubuntu, 3rd day running it now & I was following up with links, which I've realized I was following up with an old link & probably it wasn't packed  in the earlier verisions. Could reinstalling reaver mess up with the existing files?

Comment: I'm past that by now, should I post another question?
root@Sphinx-PC:~/reaver-1.4/src# airmon-ng start wlan0

Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill'

  PID Name
  837 avahi-daemon
  850 NetworkManager
  858 wpa_supplicant
  885 avahi-daemon
 4654 dhclient

PHY Interface Driver  Chipset

phy0 wlp7s0  ath9k  Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: @AmrElsokary seems to be new question. Use search before asking, then ask.

Comment: There's answers, but for different versions of Ubuntu. I believe they wouldn't be helpful & unluckily I can't ask more questions for 3 days, can you take a look on that error & tell me what's wrong?