# How to fix "ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device"?

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, atheros

```
root@Sphinx-PC:~# 
root@Sphinx-PC:~#     airmon-ng start wlan0

Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill'

  PID Name
  899 avahi-daemon
  920 NetworkManager
  922 wpa_supplicant
  966 avahi-daemon
 1096 dhclient

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlp7s0      ath9k       Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

root@Sphinx-PC:~# 
root@Sphinx-PC:~# 
root@Sphinx-PC:~#     airodump-ng mon0
Interface mon0: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
root@Sphinx-PC:~#
```

Answer (score 2):

when you try

```
root@Sphinx-PC:~#     airodump-ng mon0
Interface mon0:
```

you can't find interface mon0, instead interface wlp2s0
your wlan0 has become wlp2s0 as mon0

Try

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
airodump-ng  wlp2s0
```

Comment: <pre>root@Sphinx-PC:~# airodump-ng wlp2s0
Interface wlp2s0: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
root@Sphinx-PC:~# 
</pre>

Comment: your interface said on wlp7s0 instead wlp2s0 sir

Comment: please check my Update Answered sir

Answer (score 2):

Try running this:

```
sudo airmon-ng
```

It shows the following on my device:

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlp1s0  ath9k       Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Here you can see that my device's interface is `wlp1s0` and you can start it like this:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlp1s0
```

The interface name may be different for you. You might get something like this:

```
Found 4 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill'

  PID Name
  689 avahi-daemon
  696 avahi-daemon
  705 NetworkManager
  818 wpa_supplicant

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlp1s0      ath9k       Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

        (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlp1s0 on [phy0] wlp1s0mon)
        (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlp1s0)
```

You can see `[phy0]wlp1s0 on [phy0] wlp1s0mon`: this is the name of my device's interface, so in this case I run this:

```
airodump-ng wlp1s0mon
```

and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried this and it works.

first I typed:

```
PC@PC:~#$ sudo airmon-ng

Interface   Chipset     Driver
```

then

```
PC@PC:~#$ airmon-ng start <Interface>

Interface   Chipset     Driver

<Interface> <Chipset>   <Driver>
                        (monitor mode enabled on <mon0>)
```

Now, Interface  is ready to use, finally I typed:

```
PC@PC:~#$ airodump-ng mon0

BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID
```

Answer (score -2):

First try this

```
/usr/bin/airmon-ng
```

Using this you see interfaces, such as `wlan0mon`.

Then try this

```
airmon-ng start wlan0mon
```

and after that

```
airodump-ng wlan0mon
```

Comment: This is basically a variation of [Nandawan's superior answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1124595/348964)